# Custom Icon not Showing up in Diagrams as Code

Tags: python, diagram, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to use a `Custom` Node Type in this python diagrams as code library ([website/docs](https://diagrams.mingrammer.com/docs/getting-started/examples)] & [pypi link](https://pypi.org/project/diagrams/)). Below is (a minimal reproduceable example snippet of) my code:

```
from diagrams import Diagram
from diagrams import Edge
from diagrams.custom import Custom
from diagrams.gcp.devtools import ContainerRegistry
from diagrams.gcp.ml import AIPlatform

with Diagram(name="my_diagram",
    filename="diagrams/my_diagram_rec",
    show=True,
):

    # nodes
    vertexai = AIPlatform("Vertex AI")
    gcr = ContainerRegistry("Container Registry")
    gitlab_repo = Custom("Git Repo", "./diagrams/resources/gitlablogo.png")

    # diagram structure includind Edge attributes
    gitlab_repo >> Edge(label="Code \nConfig.yml \nEnvironment.yml") >> gcr
    gcr >> Edge(label="Docker Image") >> vertexai
    vertexai >> Edge(label="launches \nspecified \nmachine-size")
```

And confirmation that the `gitlablogo.png` file exists at the location I reference it at:

```
 ~/my-repo  issue49-diagrams $  ls diagrams/resources                ok py  17:24:23
gitlablogo.png
```

But when I run `python diagrams/so_q_diagram.py`, the image that pops up doesn't show my custom icon (the gitlab logo):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this was annoying and feels like a bug but apparently including a `filename` param in the `with Diagram(...` statement causes the custom icon to disappear. Because, without changing the location of `gitlablogo.png`, running the exact code above with one single change --commenting out `filename="diagrams/my_diagram_rec",`-- now causes the diagram image to render as expected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer doesn't work for me. I found that you have to download the icon png instead of just a picture to make the Custom function work. You can google something like "GitLab logo icon" for your situation, and you should be able to find a logo icon without any background (look like grids or mosaic). Then use the same codes you have now and it should work. Hopefully, this is helpful.

PS: example link of raspberry pi logo icon - https://icons8.com/icons/set/raspberry-pi

My result is also attached:
[flow chart with rasp_pi icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8kBW.png)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still struggling, I would suggest to mention the full path to your icon resource. In my case I had a nested folder structure something like:

- Where icon was used: project/app/diagram_generator.py
- where icon was
  placed: project/resources/icon.png

After much exploration, I ended up providing the full path of the icon.png file in my file system: **/home/<sub-directories>/project/resources/icon.png**

And it worked for me,this should have been there in the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and, from what I get, this is coming from the use of the `filename` parameter in the `Diagram()` that I was using.

In my case, to solve the issue and get the icon PNG to render properly, I used a relative path starting from the** `filename=` **location and pointing to where the icon PNG is stored.